# Can I pass the CEO title to someone else?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I just purchased the West Bank on GTA V online and started my own company.  After I hired a few of my friends, I noticed that I became a prime target for other people. Can I pass the reigns of CEO to someone else without selling my investment in the West Bank? I don't want to lose 500k (was on sale) if it forces me to get rid of the West Bank and I wouldn't mind trying out being an associate / trying the bodyguard role.

If I resign my title as CEO, do I lose the West Bank and then have to buy it again ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer is no, you can't**

You cannot give your CEO rank, warehouse(s) or office to other players in GTA Online. What you are experiencing is the "Risk VS Reward" factor. As you are successfully complete CEO related missions you will notice that you get the majority of the money while your bodyguards will get anywhere from 5000 to 10000 GTA$ depending on if you've died or not. This is because in most of the CEO missions you are the prime target.
Your sole option is to leave your CEO and work as a bodyguard for someone else. This way you can try out the bodyguard role too.

Comment: see update for an additional question

Comment: @ZeroStack You will not have to buy your office again if you choose to resign.